# Is there is a way to set async to false in XMLHttpRequest

Tags: java, gwt, xmlhttprequest

I am using com.google.gwt.xhr.client.XMLHttpRequest I'm having many failed requests with status 0, according to other peoples answers to StackOverFlow, people suggest to set async to false as follows:

```
xhrRequest.open("GET", urlWithParam,false);
```

The problem is this method is removed now from gwt library and set to true by default

```
  public final native void open(String httpMethod, String url) /*-{
    this.open(httpMethod, url, true);
  }-*/;
```

Is there is a way to set async to false?